# Wkhtmltopdf (wicked_pdf) + drawing maps (preferably Mapbox)

Tags: mapbox, wkhtmltopdf, mapbox-gl-js, wicked-pdf

anyone could help me with picking proper tools for drawing a map in PDF?

I'm using wicked_pdf on wkhtmltopdf in a Rails application to generate PDFs. As a mapping tool I'd prefer to use Mapbox.

So far I've managed to put a map in PDF only by using Mapbox Static API - so I'm getting raw PNG on backend, converting it to base64 and passing to the view and it renders and converts to pdf well.

However the problem is I'd like to draw a layer on map from a large GeoJSON and the endpoint I'm using is a GET endpoint - it supports passing GeoJSON in the URL but with my data the length of the URL is exceeded.

So I've considered using MapboxGL JS - loading it with npm to the app and then with `wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag`. However I cannot access `mapboxgl` variable - I'm getting `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: mapboxgl` (other libraries, like lodash with its `_` var are accessible this way). I've tried also using CDN and the situation is the same - ReferenceError (while it worked in just a html file I've created for tests).

So, to sum up. How should I load mapboxgl js in the view?

If not possible what other tools would you suggest for including a map with GeoJSON layers in the PDF?

Please find attached code snippets.

Layout:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <%= yield :head %>
    <%= yield :styles %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="content">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

View:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl" %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_javascript_include_tag "mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl" %>
<% end %>

...

<div id="map" style="width: 100%;height: 300px;"></div>

<script>
  try {
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'xxx';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [-74.50, 40],
      zoom: 9
    });
  } catch(e) {
    var map = document.getElementById('map');
    map.innerHTML = e;
  }
</script>
```

This results in `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: mapboxgl` rendered in my PDF.

Comment: can you add your code so we can see the problem in the code? :)

Comment: Of course, added snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've opened an issue in Mapbox (https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/8719) however they're not going to support this.

As I had features built with wkhtmltopdf I used Puppeteer only for rendering maps (Leaflet with Mapbox tiles) and I'm passing a screenshot converted to Base64 to the view for wicked_pdf.

Puppeteer/Leaflet/Mapbox set works well and I'm getting a map rendered with GeoJSON layers.

Please also find attached a great article about setting up Puppeteer on Rails and Heroku: https://www.forsbergplustwo.com/blogs/news/pdf-generation-with-chrome-headless-in-ruby-using-puppeteer-on-heroku